With Forge, how can I fetch all remotes with `forge-pull`?
With Forge, how can I fetch all remotes along with all topics with forge-pull? I want to run git fetch --all --prune when forge-pull just like magit-fetch-all-prune does.
Default behaviour for forge-pull (Nff) seems to only do git fetch --prune. Magit has "all remote" option with fa, but Forge doesn't seem to have it?

https://github.com/magit/forge is an Emacs package
